# OutofBoundException when sending an array to a method

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

public class I5Exc1a {

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] array)
{
    int[] local = array;
    int i = local.length;
    int j = 0;
    int[] arrayR = new int[i];

    for (;i>-1; i--)
    {
        arrayR[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    return arrayR;
}
```

}

It is supposed to receive an array and reverse it. but it gives me outofboundexeption when im testing it. I tried fixing it by making an extra array. I think the problem lies in the fact that the length of the array is not passed on correctly to i. Does anyone know how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from `i = local.length` and that's already out of bounds.

Look at this array:

`[0, 1, 2]` - 3 items so `length = 3`, but if you do `array[3]` there is no such element, element `2` is at index number `2`, starting from `0`. Do `i--` before your `for` loop.